# Configure grpc timeout in connection profile for peers and orderers in Hyperledger fabric

Tags: node.js, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I have multiple peers, lets say 10 peers (for example!). If one is not online (the server/container is stopped), when I try to execute a transaction the response will be

```
[Remote.js]: Error: Failed to connect before the deadline URL:grpcs://peer3:7051
```

Currently it seems it takes 3 seconds before throwing that error. I would like to reduce this to less than 1 second, since if 9 other peers are still running I would like transactions to continue executing.

When this line is executed:

```
const results = await channel.sendTransactionProposal(request)
```

It will complete in less than a second if all peers are running, however it will take a few more seconds if 1 of them is down. It would be great to configure how long to wait on connecting to a component, to be able to fail faster.

Is it possible to configure the time before that error is thrown by grpc using the Hyperledger Fabric Connection Profile?

I played with a few options shown here in the documentation but they don't seem to make a difference. https://fabric-sdk-node.github.io/release-1.4/tutorial-network-config.html

I am using Hyperledger Fabric 1.4 with Hyperledger Fabric Node SDK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's defined in the config.json of the node-sdk here https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-node/blob/7c6c7381e9094bad12e6e861de8b2d7baf308e83/fabric-client/config/default.json#L32

You can override it by exporting the environment variable `GRPC_WAIT_FOR_READY_TIMEOUT` before running your application or changing the value in config.json in the node sdk. It should be possible to override from within code as well using the `setConfigSetting` on the client instance.